# PHP Pages not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to create pages for my admin panel but when I click on my links, he can only display the `users` page and the `else`. What's wrong with my code?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["page"]) == "users") {
?>
users
<?php
} elseif(isset($_GET["page"]) == "bans") {
?>
bans
<?php
} elseif(isset($_GET["page"]) == "statics") {   
?>
statics
<?php
} elseif(isset($_GET["page"]) == "inquiries") {
?>
Inquiries
<?php
} else {
?>
    <p>Hello administrator. What would you like to do?</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `isset($_GET["page"])` returns `true` or `false`. you may do the comparision with `$_GET["page"] == "user"`, or simply use a `switch`

Comment: So `if(isset($_GET["page"]) && $_GET["page"] == "users")`

Comment: all of your conditionals are giving you false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset()` returns `true` or `false`, not the value of the variable, so you can't compare it to the value you're looking for. Use

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    if ($_GET['page'] == 'users') {
        ...
    } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 'bans') {
        ...
    } ...
}
```

Comment: ah okay I didn't know that, I'm still learning PHP, I got it now and won't forget, thanks!